# How do I replace multiple characters at once with regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
str="alex/, example/,"
new_str=re.sub(r'\s','',str)
new_str=re.sub(r'/','',new_str)
print(new_str) #example,alex
```

How can I replace to one regex instead of two ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just replacing them with nothing use the `|` for `or`:

```
re.sub(r'\s|\/', '', my_str)
```

Also, don't use `str` as a variable name.

Or you could use a group of characters to replace:

```
import re
my_str = "alex/, example/,"
new_str = re.sub(r'[\s\/]*', '', my_str)
print(new_str)
```